# how to use ConfirmIntent in Amazon Lex and Lamda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lex

I am trying to call a Intent-B from Intent-A

WelcomeBot - Intent A
AccountVerify - Intent B

When I send help from lex it will trigger the WelcomeBot Message and the below mentioned are my Lamda Response to Lex

```
{
  "dialogState": "ConfirmIntent",
  "intentName": "AccountVerification",
  "message": "Do you have your account number?",
  "messageFormat": "PlainText",
  "responseCard": null,
  "sessionAttributes": {
    "confirmationContext": "AutoPopulate"
  },
  "slotToElicit": null,
  "slots": {
    "AccountID": ""
  }
}
```

In IntentName Key I placed the AccountVerify Intent Name

But When I type "Yes" (Since I am using the ConfirmIntent) or an account number it is giving me an error message

> An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled

[image]

Comment: open up `Cloudwatch` logs and post the complete error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the Below object in case of confirmIntent.

```
{ 
   "dialogAction":{ 
      "type":"ConfirmIntent",
      "message":{ 
         "contentType":"PlainText",
         "content":"Message"
      },
      "intentName":"intentName",
      "slots":{ }
   }
}
```